# Nullifying or overriding API calls made in an Activity under an Espresso test

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, android-espresso

I have an `Activity` which performs an API call during it's `onCreate()` lifecycle method. If this call fails (which it will usually fail in a debug or test environment), a `ViewStub` is inflated which acts as an error screen. This `ViewStub` covers the rest of the `Activity`.

This causes problems while performing UI tests with Espresso. I'd like the ability to either nullify or control the outcome of this request, so that I can write predictable tests for it.

Below is the API code in the `Activity`:

```
@Override                                                                                             
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                        

    // ...                                                  

    // Perform call                                                                                   
    viewModel.loadStuff()                                                                           
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                                                                 
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                                                    
        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))                         
        .doOnComplete(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE))                                     
        .subscribe(response -> {                                              
            // Success
            // ...                                                                                         
        }, throwable -> {
            // Fail                                                                
            throwable.printStackTrace();                                                          
            errorStub.inflate();                                                                                          
        });
}
```

One of the Espresso tests I was writing was to test the enabled state of a button in this `Activity` after a few seconds. However, due to the above API call failing when under test, the button is covered by the `ViewStub` and the test fails.

I've tried implementing OkHTTP3's `MockWebServer` (note that the application uses Retrofit, not OkHTTP directly) by scripting a custom success response. However, it appears that to use `MockWebServer` you have to use the custom URL that it returns, and have your application code use that URL for it's calls. This means modifying application code to accommodate test code, which does not make sense.

I've also heard of custom Dagger setups to work around this problem.

Questions:

1. How can I setup my test so that the API call performed in the `Activity`'s `onCreate` method can be nullified or controlled?
2. If `MockWebServer` *is* the correct thing to use for this case, how can I use it without modifying application code?

General comments and tips related to this question are appreciated.

Comment: I have been through similar issues and could help here. Can you first please let me know how does the activity get that viewModel and how this viewModel was created? It's important because the way I see this you'll have to control this dependency in order to provide a mock implementation of your network call. PS: In my projects I use dagger and this makes it way easier, so if you do too mention it here and let me know how you're creating your app component

Comment: Use Dagger for dependency injection; use a custom TestRunner to instantiate a test version of your Application class, which in turn instantiates test Dagger Components which use test Modules; use Mockito to instantiate your mock Retrofit API; in your Espresso test use the Application context to get a reference to your test component and hence your mock API, this gives you full control over mocking responses. I'd say google everything here, read the documentation and try it, then post again with more granular issues/questions you run into. Dagger takes time to figure out but solves everything!

Comment: @darnmason That's pretty much what I had in mind. Is that the "normal" way of going about this? Will give it a go.

Comment: Yeah that's the best way to do it in my view, makes for clean testable code

Answer (score 2):

> How can I setup my test so that the API call performed in the
>   Activity's onCreate method can be nullified or controlled?

It seems your `viewModel.loadStuff()` is hardwired to some pre-defiend URL. To make it testable I would pass the url as parameter during viewmodel creation or pass it to the `loadStuff` method. I'll demonstrate the second option. 
The next question is how can we change the url during testing? One way to do it is to store the url in `Application` instance and override the value for testing.

**1. Create the application class which holds the url value.**

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "http://yourdomain.com/api";
    private String url;

    @Override
    void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        url = DEFAULT_URL;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    public void setUrl(String newUrl) {
        url = newUrl
    }
}
```

**2. Resolve the url value from your activity**

```
@Override                                                                                             
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                        
    // resolve url value
    String url = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getUrl();                                         

    // Perform call                                                                                   
    viewModel.loadStuff(url)                                                                           
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                                                                 
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())                                                    
        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))                         
        .doOnComplete(() -> progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE))                                     
        .subscribe(response -> {                                              
            // Success
            // ...                                                                                         
        }, throwable -> {
            // Fail                                                                
            throwable.printStackTrace();                                                          
            errorStub.inflate();                                                                                          
        });
}
```

**3. And in your test you can override the URL to use MockWebServer's URL.**

```
// Espresso Test
public class ActivityTest {

  @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockWebServer webServer = new MockWebServer();
        HttpUrl url = webServer.url("/");

        // set the url to point to mock webserver in localhost
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        app.setUrl(url.toString());
    }

    ....
}
```

You can also use shared preference to store your server url and override the value during test, but the idea is same: 
**Your view model should not be hardwired to certain URL, but instead inject the URL to the view model.**
And for resolving dependency like this, Dagger is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) (there is also [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) but setup is a little bit more complicated so let's stick with *MockWebServer*) and mock *Dagger* module.

**1. Add mock application and module**

First we need to make api module independent from *baseUrl*. We will have *BaseUrlProvider* with two implementaions (normal and mock for ui test only).

```
@Module
class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(baseUrlProvider: BaseUrlProvider): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrlProvider.baseUrl())
                .builc()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideMyApi(retrofit: Retrofit): MyApi {
        return retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

We need to provide mock implementation of *BaseUrlProvider*. Mock *baseUrl* can be stored in test application class.

```
@Module
abstract class MockBaseUrlModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindBaseUrlProvider(baseUrlProvider: MockBaseUrlProvider): BaseUrlProvider
}

class MockBaseUrlProvider(private val context: Context) : BaseUrlProvider {

    override fun baseUrl: String {
        return (context as MockApplication).baseUrl
    }   
}

class MockApplication : MyApplication() {

    var baseUrl: String = ""

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerMockAppComponent.builder().build()
    }
}
```

Custom runner is responsible for creating instance of app that is being tested.

```
class MockRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, MockApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}

android {       
    defaultConfig {        
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.foo.MockRunner"
    }
}
```

**2. Add rule**

We need to start mock server and save mock *baseUrl* in application.

```
class MockWebServerRule : ExternalResource() {

    val server: MockWebServer = MockWebServer()

    override fun before() {
        server.start()
        val app = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.applicationContext as MockApplication
        app.baseUrl = server.url("/").toString()
    }

    override fun after() {
        server.shutdown()
    }  
}
```

**3. Add test**

Request is made in activity *onCreate* so activity needs to be started manually after response is mocked.

```
class MyActivityTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MyActivity::class.java, false, null)

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val mockWebServerRule = MockWebServerRule()

    @Test
    fun testFailure() {
        mockWebServerRule.server.enqueue(MockResponse().setResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST))
        activityRule.launchActivity(null) 
        //assert view          
    }
}
```